# How I can set the signature of a function right?

Tags: haskell, option-type

I'm practicing some Haskell to understand the `\`, `case.. of` and `Maybe` better.

I've got this little function here which should return `Nothing` if the array is empty, `Just y` if y is equal to the head of the array xs and `Just (tail xs)` if y is not equal to the head of the array xs.

I set the return type of the function to `Maybe a` because in one case it should return an `Int` and in the other an `[Int]`.

```
funct :: Int -> [Int] ->  Maybe a
funct = \y xs -> case xs of
            [] -> Nothing
            xs -> if ((head xs) == y)
                        then Just y
                        else Just (tail xs)
```

What am I missing? I am getting the error that it couldn't match type `a` with `[Int]`. Isn't the `a` in `Maybe a` generic or is it influenced by the fact that I "used" the `a` as an `Int` in the `Just y` part?

**EDIT:** Ok my suggestion was bs, I tested it with `Just (tail xs)` in the then and else part and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: `y` is `t` and `tail xs` is `[t]`. You can’t have an expression that might be of type `Maybe t` or might be of type `Maybe [t]` depending on runtime conditions. One option to fix that would be to define a `data Foo a = None | One a | Lots [a]`, but that’s kind of just a list.

Comment: Read up on how Haskell's polymorphism works. If the result of a function is something with `a` this does _not_ mean the function can return a value of whichever type it likes – that would be quite useless, because how is the caller supposed to actually use the result if they don't even know the type? — Instead, a signature with `-> F a` means that _the caller may choose what type the result should be_.

Comment: In the `Foo...` - case i would replace `Maybe a` with it ?

Comment: It is possible, but you need to choose one type for the result. The simplest option here would be to always return `[Int]` – which can after all contain just a single element – or you can be more explicit and return `Either Int [Int]`.

Comment: Oh ok I guess I understand.. you're right I should read more about Haskell's polymorphism

Comment: @leftaroundabout Indeed. This error - confusing existential and universal quantification - is starting to appear quite often here. We might need a reference question so that we can close the others as duplicates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> set the return type of the function to `Maybe a` because in one case it should return an `Int` and in the other an `[Int]`.

Haskell is **statically typed**. Meaning it can not - at runtime - have a different return type. It can only have one return type. `a` is not an *ad hoc* type (in the sense that it can be any type at runtime). It means that `a` will be determined - at compile time - based on the types of other parameters.

For instance you can write: `foo :: a -> a -> a` to specify that if `foo` takes two `Int`s (again known at compile time), the result will be an `Int`.

You can however use `Either a b` to say that you will *either* return a `Left a`, or a `Right b`. So you can rewrite it to:

```
funct :: Int -> [Int] ->  Maybe (Either Int [Int])
funct = \y xs -> case xs of
            [] -> Nothing
            xs -> if ((head xs) == y)
                        then Just (Left y)
                        else Just (Right (tail xs))
```

Your function however is quite verbose, you can make it more clear and compact as follows:

```
funct :: Int -> [Int] ->  Maybe (Either Int [Int])
funct _ [] = Nothing
funct y (h:t) | h == y = Just (Left y)
              | otherwise = Just (Right t)
```

Furthermore we can generalize it to:

```
funct :: Eq a => a -> [a] ->  Maybe (Either a [a])
funct _ [] = Nothing
funct y (h:t) | h == y = Just (Left y)
              | otherwise = Just (Right t)
```

Here `Eq` is a *typeclass* that specifies that there exists a function `(==) :: a -> a -> Bool` that we can use. Otherwise using `==` in the body of the function would not be possible.

Furthermore we use *patterns* in the head of every clause. `[]` is a pattern that describes the *empty list*. `(h:t)` on the other hand is a pattern describing a list containing at least one element: the head `h`, followed by a (possibly empty tail `t`).

Comment: It really looks better the way you wrote it, but I'm learning haskell for 3-4 months yet and consider myself a bloody beginner so I just wanted to train the usage of `case` and `Maybe`. But thanks I will keep that in mind next time

Comment: @IPiiro: well I'm not saying you should use these :). It only looks - at least to me - more readable. But feel free to experiment :).

Comment: Btw where exactly is the difference between using `funct = \y xs -> case xs of...` and `funct y xs = case xs of...` ? It isn't just in terms of readability, or ?

Comment: `\y xs ->` is a lambda expression. So here you say that `funct` is a lambda expression. But it is actually equivalent. By using such variables in the head however, we can define multiple clauses each with specific patterns (like the empty list).

Comment: So in that `case` (sorry for that bad joke) it doesn't matter. Ok thank you